# Is there a way to display time data in Pandas in hours above 24 hours?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to format my time data to be displayed in hours:minutes:seconds (e.g. 36:30:30). The main goal is to be able to aggregate the times so that totals can be displayed in number of hours. I do not want to have totals in number of days.

My time data start as strings, in the format "HH:MM:SS". With pandas, I convert these to timedelta values using:

```
df["date column"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["date column"])
```

There is one record that is "24:00:00", but the above line of code gives that as "1 day".

Is there a way to display this time as 24:00:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `np.timedelta64` to change your timedelta object into a numerical representation of it self.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'hours' : ['34:00:00','23:45:22','11:00:11'] })

hours = pd.to_timedelta(df['hours']) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')


print(hours)

0    34.000000
1    23.756111
2    11.003056
Name: hours, dtype: float64
```

Comment: There is no need to use another library like Numpy, the same can be achieved with Pandas, which OP is already using. Also, the answer is wrong as OP is clearly asking for a specific format, not a "numerical representation of itself". Hours in decimals are not the same as time format.

Comment: @absay 1. Pandas' uses numpy under the hood, so making it explicit isn't a problem. 2. OP accepted the answer, if it's person who asked the question got the answer they were after. If not correct they should not have accepted it, if they have we have reason to believe the answer is correct and making assumptions is subjective and moot.